# Getting Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I am running map reduce job on four node cluster but i am getting Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: exception,

And log is -

```
MODIFY_APP APPLICATION_OWNE centos(&container_1470394245707_0015_02_000001�\ stderr 0stdout0syslog5692016-08-08 07:36:50,654 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.createLogSyncer()Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService;
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.<init>(MRAppMaster.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.<init>(MRAppMaster.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1434)
2016-08-08 07:36:50,677 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
(&container_1470394245707_0015_01_000001�\stderr0stdout0syslog5692016-08-08 07:36:48,759 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.createLogSyncer()Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService;
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.<init>(MRAppMaster.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.<init>(MRAppMaster.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1434)
2016-08-08 07:36:48,779 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1

    VERSION*(&container_1470394245707_0015_01_000001none�i�idata:BCFile.indexnoneѵ
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information about context to get an answer, I think.  What Hadoop?  What kind of job?  What are you trying to accomplish, etc.

Comment: Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.5.1
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r e1581abbb6ab62b0a41b7ce6141d7280bf0c53da
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-12-02T18:33Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 98e07176d1787150a6a9c087627562c
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.5.1.jar